# Where do I put python library folder?

Tags: python

I downloaded pythonds file for data structure.

http://www.pythonworks.org/pythonds

if I want to use this, where do I have to put it?

and how to import it?

Answer (score 1):

The best solution is to use `pip`, like this: `pip install pythonds` (might need `sudo`) and then just use it like this:

```
import pythonds
```

If you don't have `pip` installed, follow this guide: https://pip.pypa.io/en/stable/installing/.

EDIT: If you really want to use the downloaded folder, use this structure:

```
./your_folder/
|--- pythonds/
|--- your_script.py
```

And when you run `python your_script.py`, your code should work correctly.

Comment: which i downloaded from web is a folder. should i put this in somewhere? and install it?

Comment: what I meant was to use pip *instead of* downloading the folder from their website

Comment: Ok, i followed your instruction. First i piped it and it create the pythonds folder in C:\Python27\Lib\site-packages. and i tried to import it  with  import pythonds. and it gives some error but since it gives error the installation is complete. Here is the error ::::::::::::::

Comment: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#0>", line 1, in <module>
    import pythonds
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\pythonds\__init__.py", line 1, in <module>
    from .trees import BinaryTree, AVLTree, BinarySearchTree, BinHeap, BinaryTree
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\pythonds\trees\__init__.py", line 7, in <module>
    from .binaryTree import BinaryTree
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\pythonds\trees\binaryTree.py", line 81
    print('(', end=' ')
                  ^

Comment: You are using Python 2.7, and this library is only compatible with Python 3+ apparently.